# Need a way to read 20k values instead of having them in an array with 20k items

Tags: php

```
$numbers = array( 1, 24, 36, [...], 19999, 20000 );
foreach ($numbers as $nid) {

$node = node_load($nid);
$node->field_fieldname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'some value';
field_attach_update('node', $node);

}
```

I have written the above code, and i am wondering if there is a better way to have a loop over approximately 20k numbers found in this array. Could the above numbers be read from a file, where each number would be in its own row? Or what would you suggest should be the appropriate - best way to handle this?

Comment: Are you looking for a `for` loop using an index? Or the `range()` function? I don't get your question...

Comment: if they are sequential then `for($nid=1; $nid<=20000; $nid++)` or `foreach(range(1, 20000) as $nid)`.  What is the purpose of doing it a different way?

Comment: no my example was wrong... i have 20k of numbers that are ids, they are not sequential numbers

Comment: Where are you getting the list from ? Would it be possible to fetch the `$nid`s one by one ?

Comment: @homer yes, i have this list from an external report, found in a txt file. I would like to read these nids from there one by one if possible...

Answer (score 0):

Use a [generator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php):

```
function getNumbers($count) {
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    yield $i;
  }
}

foreach (getNumbers(20000) as $number) {
  $node = node_load($number);
  $node->field_fieldname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'some value';
  field_attach_update('node', $node);
}
```